# Does Jekyll support searching blog posts by multiple tags?

Tags: filtering, jekyll, blogs

Does Jekyll support searching blog posts by multiple tags? Based on the [documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/), it seems like it supports tagging posts using multiple tags, but I'm wondering if it supports being able to filter posts using multiple tags when searching for a post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `where` filter. This code filters all posts that have the tags "jekyll" and "tutorial":

```
{% assign posts = site.posts | where: "tags", "jekyll" | where: "tags", "tutorial" %}
```

You can also use the `where_exp` filter:

```
{% assign posts = site.posts | where_exp: "item", "item.tags contains 'jekyll' and item.tags contains 'tutorial'" %}
```

Learn more about [filters in the docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/).